# Yii: REST api problems

Tags: php, yii

i'm beginner in yii and in the Yii Application Development CookBook(2nd edition) on pages 105 to 113 when i'm running this codes, add button does not work, While everything is in accordance with the text of the book, where is problem? please help me.
Some code easily run but others like this are not.

controller is:

```
<?php

class TodoController extends Controller
{
     public function actionIndex()
     {
         $task = new Task();
         $this->render('index', array(
         'task' => $task,
         ));
     }

     public function actionTask()
     {
         $req = Yii::app()->request;
            if($req->isPostRequest) {
                $this->handlePost($req->getPost('id'), 
                $req->getPost('Task'));
            }
            elseif($req->isPutRequest) {
                $this->handlePut($req->getPut('Task'));

            }
            elseif($req->isDeleteRequest) {
                $this->handleDelete($req->getDelete('id'));
            }
            else {
             $this->handleGet($req->getParam('id'));
            }
     }

     private function handleGet($id)
     {
         if($id) {
             $task = $this->loadModel($id);
             $this->sendResponse($task->attributes);
         }
         else {
             $data = array();
             $tasks = Task::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'id'));
             foreach($tasks as $task) {
                 $data[] = $task->attributes;
             }
            $this->sendResponse($data);
         }
     }

     private function handlePut($data)
     {
         $task = new Task();
         $this->saveTask($task, $data);
     }

     private function handlePost($id, $data)
     {
         $task = $this->loadModel($id);
         $this->saveTask($task, $data);
     }

     private function saveTask($task, $data)
     {
         if(!is_array($data)){
             $this->sendResponse(array(), 400, array('No data
                provided.'));
         }
         // $task->setAttributes($data);
         $task->attributes = $data;
         if($task->save()) {
            $this->sendResponse($task->attributes);
         } else {
            $errors = array();
                foreach($task->errors as $fieldErrors) {
                    foreach($fieldErrors as $error) {
                        $errors[] = $error;
                    }
                }
            $this->sendResponse(array(), 400, $errors);
         }
     }

     private function handleDelete($id)
     {
         $task = $this->loadModel($id);
         if($task->delete()) {
             $this->sendResponse('OK');
         }
         else {
             $this->sendResponse(array(), 500, array('Unable to
             delete task.'));
         }
     }

     private function loadModel($id)
     {
         $task = Task::model()->findByPk($id);
         if(!$task) {
             $this->sendResponse(array(), 404, array('Task not
             found.'));
         }
         return $task;
     }

     private function sendResponse($data, $responseCode = 200,
    $errors = array())
     {
         $messages = array(
         200 => 'OK',
         400 => 'Bad Request',
         404 => 'Not Found',
         500 => 'Internal Server Error',
         );
         if(in_array($responseCode, array_keys($messages))) {
             header("HTTP/1.0 $responseCode ".$messages[$responseCode],
            true, $responseCode);
         }
         echo json_encode(array(
             'errors' => $errors,
             'data' => $data,
             ));
         Yii::app()->end();
     }
}

?>
```

and view is:

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('todo');
    $options = json_encode(array(
    'taskEndpoint' => $this->createUrl('todo/task'),
));
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('todo', "todo.
init($options);", CClientScript::POS_READY);
?>
<div class="todo-index">
    <div class="status"></div>
    <div class="tasks"></div>
    <div class="new-task">
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm()?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($task, 'title')?>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Add')?>
    <?php echo CHtml::endForm()?>
    </div>
</div>
<script id="template-task" type="text/x-dot-template">
    <div class="task{{? it.done==1}} done{{?}}" data-id="{{!it.
id}}">
    <input type="checkbox"{{? it.done==1}}checked {{?}}/>
    <input type="text" value="{{!it.title}}" />
    <a href="#delete" class="delete">Remove</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

I want when click on the add button, task added.

Comment: Can you post the error, you are getting?

Comment: just the add button does not insert data in database

Comment: it won't for the simple reason, your form is posting data to index action, not to the action task, and there is no code written in the index action to save your record, so change the action of the form to task, and it will work.

Comment: all i can guess is the package todo is supposed to submit the form using ajax to action task, but due to reason unknown to me, it is not doing so hence it isn't working, either check the package defined, check the firebug for errors, and debug them.

Comment: this code is in cookBook and i just copy that and running; however thank you.

Comment: Don't copy, you won't ever learn anything by that mean..understand and run code on your own..

Comment: `<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('/todo/task')?>` this will work..

Comment: In the veiw code, 'taskEndpoint' => $this->createUrl('todo/task'), now where is problem? while  the action of the form is task

Comment: use firebug and check the error..

Comment: now i have this: {"errors":["Task not found."],"data":[]} by using <?php echo CHtml::beginForm('/todo/task')?>

Comment: The problem is getPut() method, The rest of the code works

Comment: What is the value of the `name` attribute within the form? My guess is that it might be "task" instead of "Task" (note the upper vs. lower-case)